# How does the grading script of the LF series work for manually graded exercises?

Tags: coq, logical-foundations

I am trying to figure out how the LF test scripts output the manually graded assignments when run from the terminal.
For instance, if you look at `Induction.v` there is an exercise called `plus_comm_informal` I am trying to get the test script, `InductionTest.v` to pick up the comments or content that I write.
So I made the following attempts to monkey debug.

```
(** **** Exercise: 2 stars, advanced, especially useful (plus_comm_informal) 

    Translate your solution for [plus_comm] into an informal proof:

    Theorem: Addition is commutative.

    Proof: (* Let's see how this works! 1*)
    Let's see how this works! 2
*)

(** Let's see how this works! 3 *)

(* Let's see how this works! 4 *)

(* Do not modify the following line: *)
Definition manual_grade_for_plus_comm_informal : option (nat*string) := None.
(** [] *)
```

I saved the file. Then I compile the file with `coqc -Q . LF .\Induction.v` and then run the test file with `coqc -Q . LF .\InductionTest.v`

The output of that doesn't give me any of the comments I passed in the manually graded exercises.
The relevant section of the terminal output is as follows.

```
-------------------  plus_comm_informal  --------------------

#> Manually graded: plus_comm_informal
Advanced
Possible points: 2
Score: Ungraded
Comment: None
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't much to do about this because those exercises have to be graded manually. If you're turning this in for homework, you'll have to double-check that you did all the manual exercises yourself. If you are teaching yourself, you can give yourself a dummy grade by changing the `None.` to `Some (1, ""%string).`

Comment: I am doing this course at university, and I thought that the grading scripts extract the comments in the manually graded exercises so that instructors don't need to scroll through all the documentation and the text to find what the students have written. I think that is their intended behavior. I don't know how to get that working.

Comment: Teachers have their own scripts. Those that come with your homework are to help you track your progress, and manual exercises are not tracked.